# Update a gui table based on the input number given

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to create a table of a certain size. Lets say rows are based on a number which I need to give input to the app. and the column is fixed. only one for now.

Is this possible. For now I created manually by writing 5 times the same code .. Please help me getting through this.
Please find the attachment of the mlapp file. [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xpBDTgj-o4e6AV0Fqhc_doyuD4DejKZP/view?usp=sharing)

I am thinking to add a for loop for this section to automate it.

```
v = evalin("base",'original_proj_list');  % To import a variable from our workspace
        v = ['Select';v(:,1)];
        roll_nos = xlsread("./name_CGPA_2.xlsx");
        roll_nos = ['Select';string(roll_nos(:,1))];
        %for i = 1 : length(roll_nos)
        app.StudentInfoDropDown.Items.i = roll_nos;
        app.ProjectInfoDropDown.Items.i = v(:,1);
        app.StudentInfoDropDown_2.Items = roll_nos;
         app.ProjectInfoDropDown_2.Items = v(:,1);
         app.StudentInfoDropDown_3.Items = roll_nos;
         app.ProjectInfoDropDown_3.Items = v(:,1);
         app.StudentInfoDropDown_4.Items = roll_nos;
         app.ProjectInfoDropDown_4.Items = v(:,1);
         app.StudentInfoDropDown_5.Items = roll_nos;
         app.ProjectInfoDropDown_5.Items = v(:,1);
        %end
```

Comment: Maybe others can, but I don't follow what you actually want. Can you please be *much* more clear what it actually is that you want to do? Otherwise this is more like a homework assignment... It also helps to provide a minimal example that recapitulates the issue

Comment: Here's a short version:

@user2305193 I want to create buttons in a for loop so that I can have as many buttons as possible depending on the max limit of the loop.
The max limit of the for loop will be given by a user.

Comment: you can e.g. use this `app.StudentInfoDropDown.Items.i(ind)` to store your items in a loop (`for ind=1:maxitems, app.BLAH.i(ind)=roll_nos; end`). It's a bit unclear to my why a simple for loop wouldn't solve your issue

Comment: That is only a part of the problem. But to get these buttons automatically, I need to space them. How should I use for the positions and stuff.